# Modifying Holo Theme (ActionBar Sherlock) to put tabs above Action Bar?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on an app that uses ActionBarSherlock to provide a tabbed ActionBar interface. However, there's a possibility that our client will want the tabs to be *above* the Action Bar, rather than below it, which is the norm.

Is it possible to override the default styles to change the order of these elements? If so, what files should I look at?

Comment: What? Why would someone want the Actionbar to be below the tabs?

Comment: Sometimes "because that's what the customer wants" is the only answer to that question. Fortunately, it turns out that it's moot, because we've decided to go with list navigation instead, which is what I prefered anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change this order. In fact, the tabs my sometimes be placed inside of the action bar when space permits which would further complicate what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, Jake. Turns out we're not going to have to do this after all, so the question is now moot. But I appreciate the answer; it's good to know either way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I did this very thing by accident. I was trying to get the tabs on the bottom of the screen (think iPhone) and I set the LayoutParams to have a gravity of bottom. The tabs stayed on top, the action bar wound up right underneath them!